# Wpf - how to create a library of custom control to use and customize in differente application

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, custom-controls

I am creating a collection of custom controls in a project MyLibrary.UI. What I want to achieve is to define the some properties in a component that can be customize in every main app that uses MyLibrary.UI.

I wanto to make an example of customizing an Icon in the control FilteredComboBox.

I tried two ways:

1. I added a DependencyProperty FindImage defined in FilteredComboBox.cs:

```
 public class FilteredComboBox : ComboBox
    {
...
    #region FindImageProperty

        public static readonly DependencyProperty FindImageProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        nameof(FindImage), typeof(BitmapImage),
        typeof(FilteredComboBox),
        new FrameworkPropertyMetadata
        {
            BindsTwoWayByDefault = true,
            DefaultUpdateSourceTrigger = UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged,
            DefaultValue = new BitmapImage(new Uri("pack://application:,,,/MyLibrary.Icons;component/Icons/Find.png"))

        });

        public BitmapImage FindImage
        {
            get
            {
                return (BitmapImage)GetValue(FindImageProperty);
            }
            set
            {
                SetValue(FindImageProperty, value);
            }
        }

        #endregion FindImage


        static FilteredComboBox()
        {
            DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(FilteredComboBox), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(FilteredComboBox)));
        }
...
}
```

and modified the style FilteredComboBoxStyle.xaml as below:

```
    <ControlTemplate x:Key="FilteredComboBoxTemplate" TargetType="{x:Type local:FilteredComboBox}">
 ...
                                <DockPanel>
                                    <Image Source="{TemplateBinding FindImage}" Width="25" Height="25" DockPanel.Dock="Left"/>
                                    <TextBox x:Name="PART_SearchTextBox" Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=SearchText, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" DockPanel.Dock="Left"/>
                                </DockPanel>
 ...
    </ControlTemplate>

    <Style TargetType="{x:Type local:FilteredComboBox}"  x:Key="baseFilteredCBStyle">
...
        <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource FilteredComboBoxTemplate}"/>
...
    </Style>

    <Style TargetType="{x:Type local:FilteredComboBox}" BasedOn="{StaticResource baseFilteredCBStyle}"/>
```

Then I added the reference of this control style in Themes/generic.xaml and I defined in the resources of App.xaml of my application the following style:

```
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type local:FilteredComboBox}" BasedOn="{StaticResource baseFilteredCBStyle}">
<Setter Property="FindImage">
<Setter.Value>
<BitmapImage x:Key="myImage" Source="pack://application:,,,/MyCustomApp.Icons;component/Icons/Find.png"/>
</Setter.Value>
</Setter>
</Style>
```

I would expect that this would change the icon with MyCustomApp.Icons, but it still keeps the Icon in MyLibrary.Icons.

2. Then I tried to use a DynamicResource to set the image, so in FilteredComboBoxStyle.xaml:

```
<BitmapImage x:Key="myImage" Source="pack://application:,,,/MyLibrary.Icons;component/Icons/Find.png"/>

    <ControlTemplate x:Key="FilteredComboBoxTemplate" TargetType="{x:Type local:FilteredComboBox}">
 ...
                                <DockPanel>
                                    <Image Source="{DynamicResource myImage}" Width="25" Height="25" DockPanel.Dock="Left"/>
                                    <TextBox x:Name="PART_SearchTextBox" Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=SearchText, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" DockPanel.Dock="Left"/>
                                </DockPanel>
 ...
    </ControlTemplate>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type local:FilteredComboBox}">
...
        <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource FilteredComboBoxTemplate}"/>
...
    </Style>
```

Then in the resources of App.xaml:

```
<BitmapImage x:Key="myImage" Source="pack://application:,,,/MyCustomApp.Icons;component/Icons/Find.png"/>
```

With this approach my application shows the icon from MyCustomApp.Icons.

My questions are:

Why the option 1 is not working? There is something wrong with it?

Is the option 2 the proper way to customize the custom controls to be application-specific?

I made an example with an Image but could be any property of a control.

Comment: You know you have a typo right? `<Image Source="{TemplateBinding FindIcon}"` should be `<Image Source="{TemplateBinding FindImage}"` methinks.

Comment: Will style & template always be overridden or sometimes be overridden by the main entry point?

Comment: @PeterMoore yeah sorry I fixed my typo. I tried to summarize my code with the relevant parts. In the real code the typo does not exist.

Comment: @Andy the idea is to find the best approach to allow someone to override the style if he wants to change some properties (like the image)

Answer (score 0):

The `Themes/generic.xaml` resource dictionary should be located in the project where the custom control is defined.

If you want to set the `FindImage` property using an implicit style in the consuming application, you should put the `Style` in `App.xaml` or in a resource dictionary that is merged into `App.xaml`:

```
<Application x:Class="WpfApp1.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             ...>
    <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type local:FilteredComboBox}" BasedOn="{StaticResource baseFilteredCBStyle}">
                <Setter Property="FindImage">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <BitmapImage Source="pack://application:,,,/MyCustomApp.Icons;component/Icons/Find.png"/>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

Comment: Yeah this is what I tried to do in the Option 1. I added a dependency property for the Image I want to customize, I put the default style in Themes/generic.xaml in MyLibrary.UI and then I added the Style similar to the one you suggest in the app.xaml of my application. I thought that this is the right approach but it is not working. Unfortunately I need to work on another project for a while so this is kept in stand-by

Comment: @LucaBattistella: Well, it works for me so you are obviously doing something different.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is very difficult because it is full of typos and compiler errors. It's hard to tell where you did wrong and where you were just sloppy when creating the example. Maybe you should create the question more carefully next time.

**Option 1** is not working because you can't reference a resource defined in *Generic.xaml* from your application. *Generic.xaml* is meant as a theme dictionary for theme resources, like the default control `Style` of `FileteredComboBox`.

This means you can't base a `Style` defined in *App.xaml* on an explicitly named resource that is defined in *Generic.xaml*.

**Option 2** is working because there is no such an illegal reference to a resource that is defined in *Generic.xaml*. The `Style` in *Generic.xaml* references a resource (the `BitmapImage`) using the `DynamicResource` markup. The lookup behavior of this markup (opposed to `StaticResource`) occurs at runtime: once the application is running, lookup starts from the location of the referencing element and traverses up the logical tree to visit every `ResourceDictionary` along the route. Then the XAML engine checks the *App.xaml* and finally *Generic.xaml* for the requested resource.
In your particular case the lookup starts directly at *App.xaml*, where the XAML engine successfully finds the `BitmapImage` with the matching key.

To fix your issue, you must base the `Style` defined within the application scope on the *target type* (which will implicitly translate to the default `Style` of the styled control):

```xml
BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type local:FilteredComboBox}}"
```

**App.xaml**

```xml
<Style TargetType="{x:Type local:FilteredComboBox}"
       BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type local:FilteredComboBox}}">
  <Setter Property="FindImage">
    <Setter.Value>
      <BitmapImage x:Key="myImage"
                    Source="pack://application:,,,/MyCustomApp.Icons;component/Icons/Find.png" />
    </Setter.Value>
  </Setter>
</Style>
```

I have to point out that it is not necessary to base your `Style` on the default `Style` explicitly.
The default `Style` is always loaded first. Any additional `Style` that targets the same control will be applied commulative i.e it will be "merged" into the default style: unless `FrameworkElement.OverridesDefaultStyle` is set to `true`, only the duplicate property setters are overwritten. Otherwise the default `Style` will be completely ignored (overridden).
In other words, application scope styles are always implicitly based on the control's default `Style`.

Comment: Thanks for your clarifications. I am using FrameworkElement.OverridesDefaultStyle set to true in my custom control and the control default style is set into themes/generic.xaml in mylibrary.UI (I defined the style into a dictionary and referenced it inside generic.xaml). 
So the right solution is to base my style on 'BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type local:FilteredComboBox}}" ' instead of 'baseFilteredCBStyle'?

Comment: Yes, this is what my answer is trying to communicate. You don't even need the set the BasedOn property at all if you don't set FrameworkElement.OverridesDefaultStyle to true.